# Evaluate item multiple times

Tags: msbuild

Not sure if that the right title for the question, but what I'm trying to do is this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <item1 Include="a;b;c;"/>
    <item2 Include="x;y;z;"/>
    <itemNames Include="item1;item2"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="DefaultName">
    <Message Text="%(%(itemNames.Identity))"/>
</Target>
```

I'm expecting output to be:

```
a;b;c;
x;y;z;
```

Instead, the output is:

```
%(item1)
%(item2)
```

So my guess is that the Text property is parsed only once and the resulting string is not. Any workarounds arround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will produce the output you are looking for:

```
    <ItemGroup> 
       <item1 Include="a;b;c;"/> 
       <item2 Include="x;y;z;"/> 
       <itemNames Include="item1;item2"/> 
    </ItemGroup> 

    <Target Name="DefaultName"
       Outputs="%(itemNames.Identity)">
       <PropertyGroup>
          <ThisItem>%(itemNames.Identity)</ThisItem>
       </PropertyGroup>
       <ItemGroup>
          <ThisItem Include="@($(ThisItem))" />
       </ItemGroup>
       <Message Text="@(ThisItem)" />
    </Target>
```

...shows the following output...

```
DefaultName:
  a;b;c
DefaultName:
  x;y;z
```

Excerpted from [MSBuild Trickery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/061550907X) tricks #68 and 69